# Defining minimum radius in Scipy's cKDTree routine

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, nearest-neighbor, kdtree

I am using the query_ball_point method of scipy.spatial.cKDTree to find all the objects within a given radius R around one point.
What I want to to increase R periodically to include more and more points and save the outputs. Currently I do it like this:

```
for i in range(0,lmax+sphererads,sphererads):
  gals = kdt.query_ball_point(origin, i)
  DF[n]=pd.DataFrame(gals)
  n=n+1
```

However this way my code calculates all the distances in every iteration, including the ones it already calculated. Is there a way to specify a minimum radius Rmin for the query to start?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: KDTree needs a starting point there's no way around that. If you start your search at any distance away from that point there is no way to know if your point is connected to your search area.